# Translator of a chapter in a book is primary?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

I have a book edited by one person, each chapter of which represents a translation from ancient Egyptian into English of a given text. MWE follows.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[oldstyle,sb]{libertine}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,juniorcomma,language=british]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{Simpson:literature,
  location = {New Haven},
  edition = {3},
  title = {The Literature of Ancient {Egypt}},
  subtitle = {An Anthology of Stories, Instructions, Stelae, Autobiographies, and Poetry},
  isbn = {0-300-09920-7},
  pagetotal = {xiii+598},
  langid = {english},
  publisher = {Yale University Press},
  editor = {Simpson, William Kelly},
  date = {2003}
  }
@incollection{Wente:contendings,
  crossref = {Simpson:literature},
  title = {The Contendings of {Horus} and {Seth}},
  pages = {91--103},
  nameb = {Wente, Jr., Edward F.}
  }
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a line\autocite[99]{Wente:contendings}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that in this instance, the translator, who is in some ways an author (from the English point of view) ought to take precedence in citation. I've tried a few different approaches to coding the `.bib` file, but the result always comes out citing according to the editor.

[image: Footnote citation]

[image: Bibliography entry]

Two questions:

1. Am I wrong to think the citation should front the translator?
2. If not, how to code the `.bib` to give the desired result?

(Side-issue just in case someone knows a solution: it would be nice if the ISBN could be made to show up in the bibliography only, but my reading of the documentation is that it's an everything or nothing proposition.)

Comment: IMHO, the translator didn't write the book, hence authorship goes not to him. he needs to be mentioned though, because he's responsible for the work he did, as he could have been wrong in his translations. therefore I say, original author first, translator second. there are rules on how to deal with this, but it is heavily depending on the citation style you're using.

Comment: Well, the original author has been dead several thousand years beside bring unknown, and I would think the translator's contribution to the chapter outweighs the editor's for sure. Chicago style, as noted, but as this citation appears in a book edited by me, I'm still interested in how I might do it...

Comment: Untested, but you could pass `isbn=false` to `biblatex-chicago` then set it to true at the beginning of the Bibliography. Put this in your document preamble:`\AtBeginBibliography{\toggletrue{cms@isbn}}`

Comment: @DavidPurton I didn't try `isbn=false` because the documentation suggests it's an option to the package only. However, I added your line after the `\addbibresource` and this seemed to do the trick for the MWE. I then tried it on my actual file, which has two bibliographies per chapter (one for cited, one for consulted), and it seems to work fine there also!

Answer (score 1):

I began to ponder how I might 'promote' the translator. Searching on 'translator', I found information in the `biblatex` documentation which showed me how to do it. By adding the line `options = {useeditor=false,usetranslator=true},` to the `@incollection` item, I got the effect I wanted (as far as the primary question was concerned, anyway).

[image: Citation with editor overridden]

[image: Bibliography with editor overriden]

I would still be grateful to greater experts in style manual issues than myself to weigh in, however.

Comment: In fact `options = {useeditor=false},` alone is enough. If you want the translator to be more prominent than the editor (which I think is legitimate in some cases) that is the standard and correct way to do it.

Comment: @moewe I had the two options because the first time I tried it, with only one option, it did *not* work. Too long ago to remember, but trying each solo now, it appears that it must have been `usetranslator=true` by itself since your suggestion does indeed work. Ordinarily, I would expect myself to know to exhaust the alternatives. Must be exhaustiion from doing this while on the road!

Comment: I played around with this, and with the standard styles `usetranslator=true` is necessary in some situations. In your MWE it worked without that, but it is probably safer to include it.

Comment: @moewe Right. My actual case is much more complicated, I didn't test there yet. Appreciate the extra advice. In any case, it's definitely unambiguous that way, so it has that merit at least.