# Usage of use<name> in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

While browsing the `biblatex` documentation, I saw in Section `3.1.3.1 Preamble/Type/Entry Options` the following option:

```
 use<name>=true, false
```

On first glance, this looks potentially useful, however I am unsure how this can be used in praxis.

**Can someone give an example that uses this option? What can be inserted for `<name>`?**.

---

Example of what I naively tried to do: Enabling the `url` only for specifically selected entries. I am pretty sure I am using the command fundamentally wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    url=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@article{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  options = {useurl=true}
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
        \ifuseurl{t}{f} 
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which leads to the following error:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 \abx@macro@doi+eprint+url ->\ifuseurl 
                                       {t}{f}
```

Comment: A comment because I haven't tested think this is just supposed to apply to namelists, like `editora`, `editorb` and so forth, analogous to `useauthor`. Those lists are used for things like "director" or "producer". It's specific to those name fields, but you are trying to use it for a quite different field. That at least is how I would understand it.

Comment: @PaulStanley Thanks for the idea. Indeed, only fields of the type `list (name)` seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option is only available for name-fields. It allows you to decide whether a name is to be considered when alphabetising the entry in the bibliography. The name used for alphabetising is the name that appears at the beginning of the entry before the title. Normally the order of precedence is `author` > `editor` > `translator` > `label` > `<none>` (roughly speaking - many types drop `translator`, for some `editor` does not make sense, some styles don't know `label`, ...). With `use<name>=false` you can suppress the author from this list.

`biblatex-examples.bib` has (shortened)

```
@collection{britannica,
  editor       = {Preece, Warren E.},
  title        = {The {New Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica}},
  date         = 2003,
  edition      = 15,
  volumes      = 32,
  publisher    = {Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica},
  location     = {Chicago, Ill.},
  options      = {useeditor=false},
  label        = {EB},
}
```

This means that even though `Preece, Warren E.` is the editor of EB, he is not listed in front of the title, instead the output usually is similar to

> EB (2003). The New Encyclopædia Britannica. Ed. by Warren E. Preece. 15th ed.
>   32 vols. Chicago, Ill.: Encyclopædia Britannica.

Without this option, the entry would appear as

> Preece, Warren E., ed. (2003). The New Encyclopædia Britannica. 15th ed.
>   32 vols. Chicago, Ill.: Encyclopædia Britannica.

Note that this option does not mean that the name is dropped from the bibliography. Names that are not considered for alphabetising are usually included after the title.

Another example from `biblatex-examples.bib` (again shortened)

```
@book{vizedom:related,
  title        = {The Rites of Passage},
  year         = 1960,
  translator   = {Vizedom, Monika B. and Caffee, Gabrielle L.},
  publisher    = {University of Chicago Press},
  options      = {usetranslator},
  related      = {vangennep},
  relatedtype  = {translationof},
}
```

Normally, the `translator` is not considered to alphabetise `book`s, but with `options = {usetranslator}` (i.e. `options = {usetranslator=true}`) you allow it to be considered

With `usetranlsator=false` (default)

> The Rites of Passage (1960). Trans. by Monika B. Vizedom and Gabrielle L.
>   Caffee. University of Chicago Press. Trans. of Arnold van Gennep. Les rites
>   de passage. Paris: Nourry, 1909.

With `usetranlsator=true`

> Vizedom, Monika B. and Gabrielle L. Caffee, trans. (1960). The Rites of Passage. University of Chicago Press. Trans. of Arnold van Gennep. Les rites
>   de passage. Paris: Nourry, 1909.

Of course this can also be used to 'promote' a name over another, see [Translator of a chapter in a book is primary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367776/35864)